# send email when PutSQL failed

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to send email when `PutSQL` failed, `PutSQL`'s `Rollback on Failure=true`, as the source code does not support send email when `PutSQL` failed, so I add `REL_ALERT` relationship. I add three lines code to send email when `PutSQL` failed, but none of them works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: that's because the flowfile can be transferred only to one relation. and as soon as it already transferred in original code, your `transfer` has no effect.

Comment: @daggett, I try to clone flowfile `s.transfer(s.clone(s.create()), REL_ALERT);`, it still does not work, why?

Comment: so, it's more complicated then i thought )) if you are going to code - maby it's easier to use executegroovyscript?

Comment: The code snippet you posted in a comment won't work because you're creating a new empty flowfile and trying to clone it; you need to clone the flowfile that was returned from `session.get()` originally. See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can route a flowfile to multiple relationships (see the [Apache NiFi Developer Guide -- Route Based on Content (One to Many)](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#route-based-on-content-one-to-many) for details). I am not sure if you're saying you *want* rollback on failure to be *true*, or if you didn't realize you can change it to *false*.

If you need the rollback on failure to be true *AND* to receive an email alert, you have a couple options:

- Modify the `PutSQL` source code to clone the flowfile and send it to an `alert` relationship as above. You'll need to use code similar to [`RouteOnContent`](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/RouteOnContent.java#L227-L241) (see below).
- Register an [email log appender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender) in `$NIFI_HOME/conf/logback.xml` which gets `WARN` or `ERROR` level log events from `org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL`

**Sample code for routing flowfile to multiple relationships**

```
final Relationship firstRelationship = destinations.iterator().next();
destinations.remove(firstRelationship);

for (final Relationship relationship : destinations) {
    FlowFile clone = session.clone(flowFile);
    clone = session.putAttribute(clone, ROUTE_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, relationship.getName());
    session.getProvenanceReporter().route(clone, relationship);
    session.transfer(clone, relationship);
    logger.info("Cloning {} to {} and routing clone to {}", new Object[]{flowFile, clone, relationship});
}

flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, ROUTE_ATTRIBUTE_KEY, firstRelationship.getName());
session.getProvenanceReporter().route(flowFile, firstRelationship);
session.transfer(flowFile, firstRelationship);
logger.info("Routing {} to {}", new Object[]{flowFile, firstRelationship});
```

Comment: yes, I want `PutSQL` to rollback  and send email alert when `PutSQL` failed. Is `RouteOnContent` suitable for my situation?   I have change code to `FlowFile clone = session.clone(enclosure.getFlowFiles().get(0));session.transfer(clone, REL_FAILURE);` , but still not works.